# Долгота звука м в разных словах

Tags: орфоэпия, фонетика

В общем, я думал о том, как я произношу слово **дамба**, и мне показалось, что звук *м* продолговатый. Решил проверить другие слова похожего созвучия, например, **лампа**. Вот тут уже вроде звук короткий. На всякий случай спросил у приятеля, и у него так же. Ещё примеры: самбо, Тамбов, нимбы. Даже не знаю, я запутался.

С чем это связано, что про это известно и как это описывается?

Answer (score 3):

Звук [м] сонорный. У него три единицы звонкости из четырёх, он максимально приближен к гласным звукам, которые, как известно, тянутся бесконечно. Звук [м] тоже тянется, произносится как долгий.

На его долготу может повлиять находящийся рядом согласный звук. Если это взрывные б, п, г, к, то звук м невольно произносится короче, а если рядом другие сонорные или гласные звуки, то м кажется длинннее: земля, камни, милый. Неслучайно сонорные м, н, р, л так любят поэты: благодаря обилию сонорных, строка как бы удлиняется, звучит напевнее и мягче.